# How to write to the screen and have the output appear before the activity relinquishes

Tags: android, screen

I would like to write to an Android screen as if it were a simple terminal. I want the output to appear at the time I write it. My application does some cpu intensive churning, writes a bit to the screen and continues. I am using a list adapter for the output. The problem is that the output is not displayed until the activity relinquishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you make it all in onCreate(). Try to make it somehow like this:

1. onCreate starts a AsyncTask (see developer.android.com -> AsyncTask)
2. overwrite doInBackground with your cpu intensive churning
3. whenever you want to write to the terminal (in your case listview) call publishProgress()
4. overwrite onProgressUpdate and let it add the text to your list adapter.

maybe you could use a simple textview to display your stuff with a scrollview. or maybe a WebView. I am not sure which would be best.

A good think to look at could be the TerminalEmulator on Android for which the source can be found here:
github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator

They seem to use their own View which can be found here:
https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/blob/master/src/jackpal/androidterm/Term.java#L2527

Hope this helps.

Comment: If have been working on this solution. I have found the the publishProgress() must be called in the same code block as doInBackground. It can not be called in some other method.

Comment: I have also had trouble with calling another method from the code doInBackground code block. A simple call to another method in the file creates a RuntimeException.

Comment: I have solved my original problem based upon your suggestions. The AsyncTask did the trick. It was a struggle but I finally got it to do everything I needed. I thank you both for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: great to hear it worked :)
PS: would be nice to flag this post as the answer if it worked this way. So that other users now this question was answered and which answer shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `AsyncTask` for this.

The AsyncTask takes care of CPU-intensive work without blocking your UI. A mechanism is present to report progress back to the application, using the type of your choice.
In your case, the task can report progress updates in the form of strings; the application would simply append these strings to a text view.